# elementary circuit in a strongly connected directed graph

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Let $G$ be strongly connected directed graph with vertex set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. A circuit $i_0=i, i_1, \ldots, i_n=i$  is  elementary if path $ i_1, \ldots, i_{n-1}$ is a path in which
no vertex appears more than once.

In a paper, author claims that if  the length of any elementary circuit of $G$ is larger than or equal to 2, then there is a set $S=\{i_1,_2,\ldots, i_m\}\subseteq \{1, 2, \ldots n\}$ with  $m\leq [\frac{n}{2}]+1$ such that any elementary circuit of $G$ contains at least one vertex that belongs to $S$.

I do not know proof of it. Can you please help me to know it?

Indeed proof of the following lemme is not clear for me.

Lemma. Let  $G$ be strongly connected directed graph with vertex set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ and   the length of any elementary circuit of $G$ is larger than or equal to 2. If $i,j\in\{1, \ldots n\}$, then  there exists a (possibly empty) path $P_{ij}$ from $j$ to $i$ in $G$ that passes through at least one vertex of each (elementary) circuit of $G$ and that
has a length that is less than or equal to $\frac{n^2-1}{2}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe this.  Let $G$ be a complete graph with an arc between any two vertices in each direction.  Then every elementary circuit has length of at least 2, but $S$ would have to have at least $n-1$ vertices to be part of every elementary circuit.

Comment: @MatthewDaly, Thanks a lot. There is a lemma in this paper that I do not understand proof of it. an you please help me to know it. I add it to my question